# Change the ngmodel value in Angularjsdatepicker directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have tried to convert a bootstrap datepicker from [eternicode](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) to angularjs directive and allow to select week mode. The problem is the value {{var1}} from the view doesn't reflect to the custom value that i set on Directive

weekDatePicker directive:

```
    var app = angular.module('angular.controls', [])
app.directive('weekDatePicker', ['$filter','$parse', function ($filter, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            console.log('start');
            element.datepicker({
                //minViewMode: 1,
                //format: "MM-yyyy"                    
            }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
                scope.$apply(function () {

                    var date = e.date;// element.datepicker('getDate');
                    startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
                    endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);                  

                    startDate = $filter('date')(startDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
                    endDate = $filter('date')(endDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
                    dateText = startDate + ' - ' + endDate;
                    e.date = dateText;    

                    //console.log(e.date);
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);  //>> no change from view
                    console.log(ngModelCtrl);
                });
            });               
        }
    };
}]);
```

You can see the whole code at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8nrz6pb/1/)

View:  `<input week-date-picker ng-model="var1" class="form-control" />
    {{var1}}`  >> why it doesn't get the custom value from directive ?

Comment: var1 reflecting correct value whatever u select in calendar.. what is the exact problem?

Comment: I want to update the model value with  custom format ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);  >> should comeout with day in week like 20-04-2014 - 27-04-2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8nrz6pb/11/)

```
var app = angular.module('angular.controls', [])
app.directive('weekDatePicker', ['$filter','$parse', function ($filter, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            console.log('start');
            var ngModelParseFn = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
            element.datepicker({
                //minViewMode: 1,
                //format: "MM-yyyy",
               // language: "vi"
            })

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
            }, function (newValue) {
                var date =  element.data().datepicker.viewDate;
                startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
                endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);                  

                startDate = $filter('date')(startDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
                endDate = $filter('date')(endDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
                dateText = startDate + ' - ' + endDate;
                ngModelParseFn.assign(scope, dateText);
            });

        }

    };
}]);
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: this is what you wanted?